# How deploy Laravel Inertia app with Inertia SSR on server

Tags: node.js, laravel, deployment, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I have Laravel application, i use vue3 and inertia with SSR fore client side. It is typical laravel/jetstream app based Inertia - fully follows the documentation. I need deploy this app to VPS/VDS server. In the Inertia documentation they write how to build a client application https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering#building-your-app. It is just run `node public/js/ssr.js`, how i may do this on VPS/VDS hosting with SSH ?

Comment: why doesn't use laravel vapor for easy peasy serverless roll out to aws?

Comment: sorry, i need VPS/VDS hosting

Comment: please add more information. There is a lot to do. start the vps, connet to it via terminal, install all the infrastructure, enable the php extensions, start node, start your code.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), to run your ssr server in background,

1. install pm2, `npm install pm2 -g`.
2. go to your laravel app directory.
3. make new file ecosystem.config.json to root folder of laravel project with this command
   `nano ecosystem.config.json`.
4. copy this code for ecosystem file.
   **Note: this code for Inertia.js v1.0**

   ```
   {
   "apps": [{
       "name": "laravel",
       "script": "artisan",
       "args": ["inertia:start-ssr"],
       "instances": "1",
       "wait_ready": true,
       "autorestart": false,
       "max_restarts": 1,
       "interpreter" : "php",
       "watch": true,
       "error_file": "log/err.log",
       "out_file": "log/out.log",
       "log_file": "log/combined.log",
       "time": true
   }]
   ```

   }
5. Run pm2 with this command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.json`
6. you can see all processes status with this command `pm2 list` and check `<div>` tags on your source site.

Good luck!